# Does syncing local data to the cloud count as MFA?

Tags: passwords, password-management, multi-factor

Bitwarden uses TOTP as the multi-factor authenticator method for their password manager. Bitwarden stores and syncs your data so you need the master password + TOTP to get access to your account

Assuming we ignore Keychain, Enpass does not have an MFA method. Enpass is, however, stored locally and can be synced by the user on a cloud storage device of their choosing. Does this count as MFA or is it a less secure model (i.e: someone would have to first break into my cloud storage account and then bypass the master password)? I would use google drive as the cloud storage device for the Enpass encrypted database.

Comment: "2FA" and "multi-factor authentication" mean the same thing, so your first sentence doesn't make any sense, and in general, you seem to have only a vague idea of what 2FA / MFA is, and how it relates to other concepts. I suggest you look up an introduction to the concept, and may find your question answers itself once you've sorted the terminology out.

Comment: Your title didn't match what you asked, so I tried to provide a title that matched your actual question. And hopefully, by phrasing it this way, you can conclude what the answer would be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, syncing to cloud isn't MFA. It's syncing. And you are mixing several different things on the same question.

On Bitwarden, you have an account. It's the same as having an email account, or a forum account. To access it, you need credentials and have an option to use TOTP. If you enable TOTP, you have MFA - or 2FA in this case. If you needed password plus TOTP plus magic link sent by email, it would be 3FA.

You log in at Bitwarden and have access to your passwords. And that is different with Enpass.

Enpass, on the other hand, does not have an account per se. You can login there, but that account does not have anything to do with your password database. You can only buy more features with that login. The database is kept locally, encrypted. You can sync online like Bitwarden, but it syncs only an encrypted blob that is useless without the master password.

I am an Enpass user for yers, and I prefer how it works over Bitwarden in this respect.